# How to compare and get the difference between 2 multidim arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Could somebody pls help me with this.

I have 2 arrays arr1 and arr2

```
<?php
$arr1[0]['name'] = "Ben";
$arr1[0]['level'] = "3";
$arr1[0]['age'] = "10";
$arr1[0]['gender'] = "M";
$arr1[1]['name'] = "Chris";
$arr1[1]['level'] = "12";
$arr1[1]['age'] = "4";
$arr1[1]['gender'] = "F";


$arr2[0]['name'] = "Jack";
$arr2[0]['grade_level'] = "3";
$arr2[0]['age'] = "10";
$arr2[0]['gender'] = "F";
$arr2[1]['name'] = "Lily";
$arr2[1]['level'] = "2";
$arr2[1]['age'] = "7";
$arr2[1]['gender'] = "F";
$arr2[2]['name'] = "Chris";
$arr2[2]['level'] = "12";
$arr2[2]['age'] = "4";
$arr2[2]['gender'] = "M";
?>
```

I need to compare the difference between arr1 and arr2 (and vice versa) on entries that have the same level and age values and return/highlight the columns that didn't match.

ex: 
Ben->3->10->M in arr1 will be compared to
A.1 Jack->3->10->F in arr2 because they have the same level and age values

Chris->12->4->F in arr1 will be compared to
A.2 Chris->12->4->M in arr2 because they have the same level and age values

I should be able to know which columns didn't match
for A.1 the return should be name & gender
for A.2 the return should be gender

Desired output:
http://s7.postimage.org/8r3tf24rf/img.png

I have tried array_diff and several array functions & manipulations but i can't come up with the desired result :(
pls help. Thanks!

Comment: Your example only has two level. Is it true for your real data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example use "helper arrays" ($hl highlighter) that'd look like this:

```
<?php
$arr1[0]['name'] = "Ben";
$arr1[0]['level'] = "3";
$arr1[0]['age'] = "10";
$arr1[0]['gender'] = "M";
$arr1[1]['name'] = "Chris";
$arr1[1]['level'] = "12";
$arr1[1]['age'] = "4";
$arr1[1]['gender'] = "F";


$arr2[0]['name'] = "Jack";
$arr2[0]['level'] = "3";
$arr2[0]['age'] = "10";
$arr2[0]['gender'] = "F";
$arr2[1]['name'] = "Lily";
$arr2[1]['level'] = "2";
$arr2[1]['age'] = "7";
$arr2[1]['gender'] = "F";
$arr2[2]['name'] = "Chris";
$arr2[2]['level'] = "12";
$arr2[2]['age'] = "4";
$arr2[2]['gender'] = "M";

$hl1 = array();
$hl2 = array();

foreach($arr1 as $x => $tester)
{
    foreach($arr2 as $y => $testing)
    {
        if(($tester['level'] == $testing['level']) AND ($tester['age'] == $testing['age']))
        {
            foreach($tester as $key => $value)
            {
                if($testing[$key] != $value)
                {
                    $hl1[$x]['pos'] = true;
                    $hl1[$x]['key'][] = $key;
                    $hl2[$y]['pos'] = true;
                    $hl2[$y]['key'][] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$printheader = true;
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($arr1 as $pos => $printer)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if($printheader)
    {
        $header = array_keys($printer);
        foreach($header as $key)
        {
            echo "<td>". $key ."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $printheader = false;
    }
    foreach($printer as $key => $value)
    {
        if(isset($hl1[$pos]) AND in_array($key, $hl1[$pos]['key']))
        {
            echo "<td style='background-color: ff0000;'>". $value ."</td>";
        }
        else
            echo "<td>". $value ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$printheader = true;
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($arr2 as $pos => $printer)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if($printheader)
    {
        $header = array_keys($printer);
        foreach($header as $key)
        {
            echo "<td>". $key ."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $printheader = false;
    }
    foreach($printer as $key => $value)
    {
        if(isset($hl2[$pos]) AND in_array($key, $hl2[$pos]['key']))
        {
            echo "<td style='background-color: ff0000;'>". $value ."</td>";
        }
        else
            echo "<td>". $value ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

looks like this: http://anyimg.com/view/8pj5q71/table_out.png